# Can I limit a search to a specific class in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working on a codebase with very large files with dozens of classes each.
Sometimes I want to search for something within the methods of a specific class, for example all matches of a regular expression within all methods of `class A` inside `myfile.cpp`.

Can this be done with vscode? Thanks!

Comment: <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd> ("Go To Symbol in Workspace") + "<class name>" ..works also for "inner classes" (but without fancy wildcards ;(nor regex;(;( ..at least for java;)

Comment: This very well could be possible but I would need to see some sample code.  And do you want to do this in multiple files at once or just in the active editor?

Comment: @Mark only in the active editor. Can't give an example code right now, but most files in my code base are somewhere in the 15-20k lines of code and is comprised of state machines classes. Usually all methods of a certain class are in the same file, in the same place , one after the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open the file you want to search.
2. Select the section within the file you want to search in.
3. Press ctrl+f like for a regular search.
4. Press alt+l to narrow down the search to the section you selected.

this should do it but there may be a faster way which i don't know about.

Comment: mm not exactly what I was looking for but does the job. Thanks!